# Codeigniter htaccess redirections not redirecting to desired url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a codeigniter website which I want to do seo on. So i used routes for sluggish urls rather than the codeigniter default having method name and indices.
With this a problem comes in play, three different urls it opens the same page ie.

```
1. https://www.example.com/seo-freindly-url/
2. https://www.example.com/index.php?/controller/method/42
3. https://www.example.com/controller/method/42
```

But I want only the first url to work, for others i want to redirect to the seo friendly one by only using **htaccess** redirections. 
Please Help me in that.
One more thing i used htaccess 301 redirection to redirect one of my urls

```
Redirect 301 "/plan/index/42" https://www.example.com/services/seo
```

It works to some extent, whenever I open the url

```
https://www.example.com/plan/index/42
```

it redirects to

```
https://www.example.com/services/seo?/plan/index/42
```

but it has to be https://www.example.com/services/seo/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to test on my end, but you might try something like this:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^controller/method/42$ /seo-friendly-url [L]

redirect 301 /plan/index/42 /services/seo

RewriteRule ^(system|application|cgi-bin) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Remove index.php from all URLs
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

/application/config/config

```
// This assumes you want to remove index.php from all URLs
$config['index_page'] = '';
```